# How can i create 404 Page Not Found in react-router-dom V5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use `react-router-dom` V5. When I create `Route` component in my project I use `<HashRouter>`.

This is example of my component:

```
<HashRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/form" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/admin" component={Panel} />
    <Route path="/changepass" component={ChangePass} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

For example when I enter: `"/akfakafk"` it works correctly, but when I enter: `"/admin/wtwtwtw"` it's not working.

I know it is not implemented correctly,

**I want to know, how can I implement this?**

By the way in `"/admin"` render `Panel` component that has return  another routes.

This is my  panel routes:

```
const dashboardRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: dashboard,
    icon: DashboardIcon,
    component: DashboardPage,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
  {
    path: "/devicesManagement",
    name: devicesManagement,
    icon: DevicesIcon,
    component: DevicesPage,
    layout: "/admin",
  }
]
```

Comment: Does `"/admin"` route render any descendent routes? In other words, does `Panel` render any `Route` components? Can you share the `Panel` component code?

Comment: yes for example "/admin" route render "/admin/dashboard",

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that in RRDv5 all route paths are effectively path "prefixes", meaning for example for path `"/admin"` that ***all*** `"/admin/*"` paths can be matched by it and rendered.

If there are no descendent routes you can use the `exact` prop on routes you want to *exactly* match.

Example:

```
<HashRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/form" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/admin" exact component={Panel} />
    <Route path="/changepass" component={ChangePass} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

Here `"/admin"` will be matched and render the `Panel` component, but `"/admin/wtwtwtw"` will not and the `NotFound` component will be rendered as expected.

If there are descendent routes then you sould again render another `Switch` component and routes and either another general "not found" route or redirect to a more general "not found" route.

Example:

```
<HashRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/form" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/admin" component={Panel} />
    <Route path="/changepass" component={ChangePass} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

...

```
const Panel = props => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${path}/dashboard`} component={DashboardPage} />
      <Route path={`${path}/devicesManagement`} component={DevicesPage} />
      ...
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Comment: thank i will test it.  and tell you Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @MohammadrezaAtaei An alternative is to create a single route, like `path="/404"` and render `<Redirect to="/404" />` instead of multiple `<Route path="*" component={NotFound} />`, but it's basically the same thing.

Comment: redirect from  what   to "/404" ?

Comment: @MohammadrezaAtaei Any route path that isn't handled by any `Route` above it in the `Switch` component. Would a code example be helpful here?